# How to replace "on , in , or , and , of , the"

Tags: php

I have string like this

```
$string = "the man on the platform"
```

than i trim and remove white space

```
$words =    explode(' ', trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string)));

print_r($words);
```

Result

```
Array ( [0] => the [1] => man [2] => on [3] => the [4] => platform)
```

How can i remove 'on' and 'the' to get result like this that i can use later to loop and search in DB

```
Array ( [0] => man [1] => platform)
```

Comment: you can test out which is faster later but i think its better to just handle everything on the regex instead of exploding the string and using array functions on it later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve your desired result is to use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with a list of stopwords (words to be deleted):

```
$string = "the man on the platform";
$words =  preg_split('/\s+/', $string);
$stop_words = array('on', 'in', 'or', 'and', 'of', 'the');
$words = array_filter($words, function ($v) use ($stop_words) { return !in_array($v, $stop_words); });
print_r($words);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => man
    [4] => platform
)
```

Note that instead of using `preg_replace` to convert sets of spaces into a single space and then calling `explode`, you can just use [`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and split on a set of spaces.

Also, you can make this slightly more efficient by using the stop words as keys in the array, allowing use of `isset` instead of `in_array` in the filter function:

```
$stop_words = array('on' => 1, 'in' => 1, 'or' => 1, 'and' => 1, 'of' => 1, 'the' => 1);
$words = array_filter($words, function ($v) use ($stop_words) { return !isset($stop_words[$v]); });
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/C964h)

Comment: This work perfect , is anyway also that i can match and 't' at end of the words like " don't " or at beginning 'x' like "x100"

Comment: @GameClubStreaming I'm not sure exactly what you mean? do you want to delete a word which finishes with `'t` e.g. `don't` and ones which start with e.g. `x` like `x100`? but what about e.g. `xylophone`?

Comment: sorry bad example i mean something like Women's to become Women or something like x100 to become 100

Comment: @GameClubStreaming you'd have to do some regex replace. Something like this could be a good starting point: https://3v4l.org/AdjZ6, if you can't get it working I suggest asking a new question as it is quite a different problem to this one.